# $.when( 2 conditions ).then(function(){});

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do:

```
$.when(app.loadDevice && app.loadReady).then(function(){
   //Execute code
});`
```

But my code seems to execute when the first condition fires up with app.loadDevice.resolve()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the `&&` operator with two JavaScript objects, the result is the value of the first object, so that's the only one that `$.when` is considering. The second object isn't even being evaluated.

Instead, you want to pass both objects as different arguments to the `$.when` function:

```
$.when(app.loadDevice, app.loadReady).then(function(){
    //Execute code
});
```

You can see this in some of the examples [in the official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Comment: A quick tip for anyone coming across this, if you have an array of deferreds and you want to wait for all of them to complete you can use `$.when.apply( $, deferredsArray );`